# Exchange Label background with pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to toggle exchange the background-image of a label when I click on it AND the checkbox belonging to it is checked or unchecked; all of this with pure CSS.

Explanation: The label we are talking about is the mobile menu button and when the menu opens it should change to an X instead of the three horizontal bars. When the menu is closed it should go back to normal.

How can I achieve this in this existing context (see jsfiddle)?

[jsfiddle with the existing functionality of the menu](https://jsfiddle.net/gav2out1/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id="mobile-navigation" class="hidden-xl">
<label for="nav-trigger" id="label-trigger"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here goes the CSS with it:

```
#mobile-navigation {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

#menu {
    display: none;
}

#menu li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "RotisRoman", Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color: #999;
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("http://www.circlecafebar.co.uk/photographs/nav-button.jpg");
}

/*this should be the image replacing the labels image*/
.nav-open {
    background-image: url("/_images/close_btn.png");
}

#nav-trigger {
    display: none;
}

.nav-trigger {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nav-trigger:checked + #menu {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 85px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Comment: This is only possible if you place the label *below* the checkbox in your markup.

Comment: @connexo and then the current functionality won't work anymore, right? :s

Comment: You need to change it a little bit. See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic selector is `~`

```css
#mobile-navigation {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

#menu {
 display: none;
}

#menu li {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 background-color: none;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "RotisRoman", Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#menu li a:hover {
 color: #999;
}

#bodarto {
 margin-top: 45px;
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
 position: fixed;
 left: 30px;
 top: 30px;
 z-index: 2;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-image: url("http://www.circlecafebar.co.uk/photographs/nav-button.jpg");
}

input:checked + label {
 background-image: url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1714/dropline_neu/48/dialog_close.png");
}

#nav-trigger {
 display: none;
}

.nav-trigger {
 position: absolute;
 clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ #menu {
 display: block;
 list-style: none;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 40px 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 85px;
 z-index: 2;
 background-color: #d8d8d8;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mobile-navigation" class="hidden-xl">
   <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
   <label for="nav-trigger" id="label-trigger"></label>
   <ul id="menu">
       <li><a href="lorem.php" title="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="" title="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="" title="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="/kontakt.php" title="">Kontakt</a></li>
       <li id="bodarto"><a href="http://www.bodarto.ch/" target="_blank"><img src="_images/bodarto.png" alt="" border="0" /></a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: In this case the adjacent sibling selector `+` would be the superior solution over the general sibling selector. `~`.